# Updating off-topic questions in help center

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

I recently asked a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81142/10870) that was voted off-topic. This, and similar cases could be avoided if there were a description of blender-related off-topic questions in the help center (this is the first destination that is recommended by the site for info on the subject).

I see that similar attempts have been made in the past to make the help center more informative about undesirable blender-related questions, such as [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/595/10870) and [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/10870). It looks like they were never implemented however.

Anyway, I wanted to suggest from my own experience, and for the benefit of future answer seekers, to include in the help center a sentence saying something along the lines of:

"Questions about unreleased versions of blender are off-topic".

Comment: "looks like they were never implemented" but why this list https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6/1245 isn't counted as implemented? There isn't unreleased versions, but your case can fall under techincal questions; also related discussion was there in comments.

Comment: @MrZak, by not implemented, I meant that the goal of those questions  was to add info to the help center (the one you linked has an update where the person suggested to edit the help center). But at present I don't see any of it there. I don't know what exactly happened, I wasn't present back then, but I can talk about what I (don't) see now.

Comment: FYI we are discussing whether 2.8 questions are on topic or not, so until that is decided editing the help center (at least on this point) would not help.

Comment: Oh, I assumed it was pretty much settled [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2349/10870)